# Grafana alert for Kafka metric Active Controller Count

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, grafana, alerts

I have a dashboard in Grafana that I will use to monitor a Kafka instance. I can get the metrics using Prometheus.

The metric is called **active controller count** and It is very important to monitor Kafka.

I got what I want using the metric **kafka_controller_kafkacontroller_activecontrollercount_value{job="kubernetes-service-endpoints"}**

[image]

**In any moment only one of the 3 metrics must be equal 1 and the other two must be equal 0.**

How can I make an alert that fires when the condition above is not satisfied?

I tried the following but with no success:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I used the **sum** function:

[image]

An alert will fire if the sum is not equal 1.

[image]